# Grant access to the extended properties of a sql server database

Tags: security, sql-server-2008

In Sql Server 2008,

Our database uses an extended properties. We noticed that a user that does not have the sysadmin role cannot read any extended properties.

What access should be granted to allow a user that has the public role to read the extended properties?

Answer (score 0):

If they have been [granted Select rights](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190243.aspx) on the table they should have read rights on the extended properties.